# “Robo 3T” cannot be opened because the developer cannot be verified

Tags: mongodb, macos, robo3t

I have installed the Robo 3T using the Homebrew tool.

```
brew install --cask robo-3t
```

after installing I am getting pop-up windows asking on macOS.

> “Robo 3T” cannot be opened because the developer cannot be verified.

Answer (score 38):

Workaround:

Go to System Preferences -> Security and Privacy -> General
Towards the bottom, a message is shown that Robo 3T is blocked. Select Open Anyway.

That should do the work!

Comment: But it doesn't for me! This what I usually do in cases when MacOS complains that the developer can't be verified, usually it works, but not in this case with Robo 3T!

Comment: ... and after a reboot it worked ... sigh.

Answer (score 9):

I had the same problem, and HERE's how I solved it: I executed it on the command line

```
sudo xattr -r -d com.apple.quarantine /Applications/Robo\ 3T.app
```

Comment: props for providing a cli answer!

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

`Finder > Applications > Robo3t > right click (two fingers) > Open`